# NSDateFormater - returns same year for 2015 and 2016 date

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have found a strange behaviour in `NSDateFormatter` with `LLLL YYYY` format, where it returns year **2015** for both **2015-01-01** and **2016-01-01** dates.

Am I missing something or is it a bug in the formatter class?

Code to reproduce:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"LLLL YYYY";

NSDate *d1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1420070400]; // 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z
NSDate *d2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1451606400]; // 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z

NSLog(@"%@ => %@", d1, [formatter stringFromDate:d1]); // 2015-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 => January 2015
NSLog(@"%@ => %@", d2, [formatter stringFromDate:d2]); // 2016-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 => January 2015
```

Both cases print "January 2015", but I would expect "January 2016" in the second case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Comment: It's that time of the year again!!! Mac and iOS apps breaking left, right and center in the first days of the new year, because yyyy and YYYY are confused! What will be more confusing is next year when code will go wrong on Sunday, Jan 1st 2017, but only in Europe, not in the USA (but you should test that, I might be wrong).

Answer (score 7):

You should use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`, because `YYYY` is something different...

A deeper explanation from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> A common mistake is to use
>   YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year
>   (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most
>   cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be
>   different. Typically you should use the calendar year.